# Javascript is conflicting

Tags: javascript

I have 2 different tabbed sections on a page but the javascript is conflicting and not allowing them to work together.  If I remove one it works and vice versa.  I need each one to open with the first tab image open by default but having both of them set that way only allows 1 image to open.  I not real good with javascriptHere is my code:

This is for the first tabbed section -

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
   var i, apartmentimg, tabapartment;
   apartmentimg = document.getElementsByClassName("apartmentimg");
   for (i = 0; i < apartmentimg.length; i++) {
    apartmentimg[i].style.display = "none";
  }
   tabapartment = document.getElementsByClassName("tabapartment");
   for (i = 0; i < tabapartment.length; i++) {
   tabapartment[i].className = tabapartment[i].className.replace("   active", "");
  }
   document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
   evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }

  window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
  };
```

This is for the 2nd tabbed section -

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, patioimg, tabpatio;
    patioimg = document.getElementsByClassName("patioimg");
    for (i = 0; i < patioimg.length; i++) {
        patioimg[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tabpatio = document.getElementsByClassName("tabpatio");
    for (i = 0; i < tabpatio.length; i++) {
        tabpatio[i].className = tabpatio[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
};
```

How can I combine these so they don't conflict with each other and each one opens with the first image by default?

Here is the page - https://vcs-dev.info/our-locations/vincentian-villa/

It is the 2 sections with floor plans.

Comment: It looks like this is a good opportunity for refactoring. Identify what differs between the two implementations and consider pulling those differences out in to parameters. For example, maybe you could pass in the two classes you are referencing. Then you would just have to one function that you would call in two different places with different arguments.

Comment: I'm not trying to be insulting but you may be offended by this. Everyone has to learn at some point so there's no ill will here, but the code you're referring to on that page is structurally awful. So much so that I would suggest to start over from a blank slate and build up from there asking questions as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  How would I do something like that?

Comment: I'm not offended, I got that code from w3schools.com. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp. I don't know much javascipt so I don't know if it's bad or not.

Comment: @Peggy well, when you say open the first tab image what are you referring to? I'm pretty confused about the issue you're trying to resolve.

Comment: @zfrisch - I need it set up as 2 sections.  Once I style it there will be a floor plan on the left side of the page and another one on the right side of the page. (Apartment floor plan tabbed section & Patio Homes tabbed section).  Each one will have tabs to view each floor plan.  I need the image that shows on the first tab when the page is loaded for each floor plan.  I hope that makes better sense.